# local nginx https server send error certificates: mediarouter.home

Tags: nginx, certificates

I set up a website server on my system via nginx, When I visit my site remotely, everything goes right, but when I visit this site locally(via write domain name in /etc/hosts), nginx will send wrong certificate, here is chrome prompts:

```
Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.xiedeacc.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
Subject: mediarouter.home
Issuer: root.home
Expires on: Jul 11, 2024
Current date: Sep 23, 2017
PEM encoded chain:
```

Comment: What ip address is used remotely and what locally ? I am guessing they differ.

Comment: yes, you're right, I have fixed it by change /etc/hosts

Answer (score 1):

From the comments the problem was caused by using a different ip address in /etc/hosts

Once `/etc/hosts` was updated, presumably to the public ip, it works as expected.